# Cordova FileTransfer and Cordova Camera

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working in Ionic with some cordova plugins (FileTransfer, Camera, File, etc).

[view - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIiqu.jpg)

On the view works great, I can show images(camera and gallery) but I get a FileTransfer error code = 1 when try to upload and it means File not found. So when I check my app directory (cordova.file.dataDirectory and cordova.file.cacheDirectory) is empty.

Camera Code:

```
$scope.takePhoto = function(){
var optionsCamera = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
  correctOrientation: true
};

$cordovaCamera.getPicture(optionsCamera)
  .then(function(imageData){

    console.log(imageData);

    var currentName = imageData.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    var namePath = imageData.substr(0, imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    console.log(currentName);
    console.log(namePath);
    //move from cache to files
    $cordovaFile.moveFile(namePath, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, 't_s'+currentName)
      .then(function(successMove){
        console.log(successMove);
        $scope.imagenes.push('t_s'+currentName);
        console.log($scope.imagenes);
      }, function(errorMove){
        console.log(errorMove);
      });

  }, function(errorCamera){
    console.log(errorCamera);
  })}
```

Upload code:

```
$scope.sendData = function() {

var server = Config.serverUrl() + '/product_image_upload/';

console.log($scope.imagenes);
//first image in array
var targetPath = $scope.imagenes[0];
var filename = ($scope.imagenes[0]).replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
console.log(targetPath);
console.log(filename);

var options = {
  httpMethod: 'POST',
  fileKey: 'file',
  filename: filename,
  chunkedMode: false,
  mimeType: 'multipart/form-data'
};

var params = {
  'fileName' : filename,
};
//JWT token
var headers = {
  'Authorization': $rootScope.token
};
options.headers = headers;
options.params = params;
console.log(options);
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, targetPath, options).then(
  function(result) {
    // Success!
    console.log('upload ok');
    console.log(result);
  }, function(err) {
    // Error
    console.log(err);
  }, function(progress) {
    // constant progress updates
    console.log(progress);
    $scope.progress = progress;
  })}
```

I want to know, where  are the files?

Comment: So what you want to ask ?

Comment: I want to know, where  are the files?

Comment: You've got a lot of `console.log` statements -- care to share what they print out?

Comment: Yes, Now I can see the img files on my cellphone using File Commander(App) but same troble. File Not Found code.